# lodash: How to do case insensitive _.find()

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a complex data structure, with nested arrays and I need to find an element with a string value using a case insensitive search.

I've started using lodash due to the simple syntax to perform nested queries - it works great but the search is case sensitive.

I want to find an "address_components" element with a "types" value of 'route' and "long_name" value equal to a parameter called 'targetStreet'.

Here is the lodash code I have so far:

```
    var result = _.find(geocodeResult,
        {
            'address_components': [
                {
                    types: ['route'],
                    'long_name': targetStreet
                }
            ]
        });
```

**Question:**
How can I make the matching of the "long_name" property case insensitive?

Below is an example of the 'geocodeResult' data structure (its actually a Google Geocoding Result object).

Note that this data structure is dynamic...Google will return the most specific result it can, but if it can't find a match for a street, then it wont return the street component e.g. the "types" array within "address_components" has non-deterministic values.

```
    [
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "V&a Lane",
        "short_name": "V&a Ln",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Coonawarra",
        "short_name": "Coonawarra",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Wattle Range Council",
        "short_name": "Wattle Range",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "South Australia",
        "short_name": "SA",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Australia",
        "short_name": "AU",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "5263",
        "short_name": "5263",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "V&a Ln, Coonawarra SA 5263, Australia",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "south": -37.3238134,
        "west": 140.8154452,
        "north": -37.3228868,
        "east": 140.97295129999998
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": -37.3233904,
        "lng": 140.89510410000003
      },
      "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
      "viewport": {
        "south": -37.3246990802915,
        "west": 140.8154452,
        "north": -37.3220011197085,
        "east": 140.97295129999998
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true,
    "place_id": "EiVWJmEgTG4sIENvb25hd2FycmEgU0EgNTI2MywgQXVzdHJhbGlh",
    "types": [
      "route"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "V&a Lane",
        "short_name": "V&a Ln",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Coonawarra",
        "short_name": "Coonawarra",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Wattle Range Council",
        "short_name": "Wattle Range",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "South Australia",
        "short_name": "SA",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Australia",
        "short_name": "AU",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "5263",
        "short_name": "5263",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "V&a Ln, Coonawarra SA 5263, Australia",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "south": -37.3238134,
        "west": 140.8154452,
        "north": -37.3228868,
        "east": 140.97295129999998
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": -37.3233904,
        "lng": 140.89510410000003
      },
      "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
      "viewport": {
        "south": -37.3246990802915,
        "west": 140.8154452,
        "north": -37.3220011197085,
        "east": 140.97295129999998
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true,
    "place_id": "EiVWJmEgTG4sIENvb25hd2FycmEgU0EgNTI2MywgQXVzdHJhbGlh",
    "types": [
      "route"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use `lodash.find` correspond to `lodash.match` shorthand (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find), unfortunately you can't pass regexp or function to get an insensitive search in your object properties.

You have to write something like that to perform the search (assuming `targetStreet` in lower case) :

```
var result = _.find(geoCodeResult, function (result) {
   return _.find(result.address_components, function(component) {
      return _.includes(component.types, 'route')
        && component.long_name.toLowerCase() === targetStreet;
   });
});
```

You can also write it without `lodash`, using ES6 syntax + [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (for recent browsers)

```
const result = geoCodeResult.find(result => 
   result.address_components.find(({ types, long_name }) => 
      types.includes('route') && long_name.toLowerCase() === targetStreet
   ));
```

Answer (score 11):

Convert the two values to the same case before comparison.

```
var search = 'Australia'.toLowerCase();

var result = _.find(geoCodeResult, function (location) {
    return location.long_name.toLowerCase() === search;
});
```

Comment: This wont work for the given data structure. Your function will run once for every object in the collection. In my example, there are two. Those objects in turn have six properties...the only one of which I'm interested in is "address_components". And then within that...I need to check if there is a "types" array with a value "route" (it might not be there)...and if so, then I need to check the "long_name" property...So you have to get the nesting right AND we can't rely on the properties being there.

Comment: Fair enough. I was answering the question `How to do case insensitive _.find()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can search case insensitive using lodash _.find() function

```
const propertyName = "Basic";
const findName = _.find(this.object, item => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase() === propertyName.toLowerCase();
    });
```